# javascript - assigning mutiple strings to a single string under variable assignment

Tags: javascript

I have a **javascript** variable (facet field 'source') is defined as

```
var source = {
    'www.abc.com/1/'  : 'ABC',
    'www.def.com/1/'  : 'DEF',
    'www.ghi.com/1/'  :'GHI',       
};
```

In the above example, ABC, DEF and GHI are used for displaying facet field values. So, urls such as www.abc.com will all be grouped under 'ABC' facet value, urls with www.def.com will all be grouped under 'DEF' facet value  under facet field named "Source".

**Actual problem:** Now I have two urls which I want to be included under a single facet value 'GHI' like the one shown below

```
var source = {
    'www.abc.com/1/'  : 'ABC',
    'www.def.com/1/'  : 'DEF',
    'www.ghi.com/1/'  :'GHI', 
    'www.ghi.com/2/'  :'GHI',   //trying to add this    
};
```

The problem with the above is, it creates two facet values with same name 'GHI' under facet field 'Source'. I want urls of both forms 'www.ghi.com/1/' and 'www.ghi.com/2/' to be under a single facet value 'GHI'. So ideally on the front-end, there should be only one 'GHI' and when I click on that, it should list both urls 'www.ghi.com/1/' and 'www.ghi.com/2/'

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for a Map, which in JavaScript should be done like that:

```
var source = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'];

var urls = {};
urls['ABC'] = new Array();
urls['DEF'] = new Array();
urls['GHI'] = new Array();
urls['ABC'].push('www.abc.com/1/');
urls['DEF'].push('www.def.com/1/');
urls['GHI'].push('www.ghi.com/1/');
urls['GHI'].push('www.ghi.com/2/');
```

So, to get all URLS matching 'ABC', you would have:

```
var arrayOfABC = urls['ABC'];
```

To get the first entry of the array:

```
var url = urls['ABC'][0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Jalayn. I still have the same problem. With the approach you mentioned it still creates two 'GHI' facet values - when i click on the first one it lists 'www.ghi.com/1/' and when i click on the second one, it lists 'www.ghi.com/2/'

Comment: is there any way to mention something like this in javascript? source ['www.ghi.com/1/', 'www.ghi.com/2/'] = 'GHI';

Comment: Check out my edit, is that what you want ? Now, in source['GHI'] you have an array of URLs

Comment: no, it did not work! it completely ignored 'GHI', under the facet field "Source", the two urls are directly displayed as 'www.ghi.com/1/' and 'www.ghi.com/2/' instead of 'GHI'

Comment: I am trying to do something similar to this: http://evolvingweb.github.io/ajax-solr/examples/reuters/index.4.html - in this link, when you hover over "acq" under facet field "Top Topics" on the left side, you can see a url for "acq". All I am trying to do is assign two different urls to a single "acq" in this example

Comment: that's because source['GHI'] now returns an array, not an object. So you have to take that into account. Could you please edit your question to also add your HTML so we can help you better ?

Comment: please see the link I posted in my above comment

Comment: I edited my answer to distinguish between the source and the urls, but If I understood you correctly, this is really what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your code completely makes sense and the jsfiddle was helpful. Thank you. But I still have the same issue which I think is more to do with the way faceting works in Ajax/Javascript. I am working on a project that is based on this: https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/wiki/Reuters-tutorial%3A-step-4

Comment: Glad to help, I'm sorry though, but I don't know apache solr or ajax/solr, maybe you could ask another question more specific to solr ? I'm sure somebody can answer this as there is a "solr" tag in Stack Overflow.